# How to call a method from a different class comparing two values?

Tags: java, bluej, currency

I am trying to figure out how to call the `boolean isAfter(Date compareTo)` in my `Date` class in my `Bill` class. I keep getting an error message saying "cannot find symbol - method isAfter(Date). I know what I have is not right. Do I have to create a new `Date` object in my `setPaid` method?

Here are the methods from my `Date` class--runs fine and the entire `Bill` class--does not.

```
public boolean isAFter (Date compareTo) {
    return compareTo(compareTo) > 0;
}

public int compareTo (Date x) {
    if (year != x.year) return year - x.year;
    if (month != x.month) return month - x.month;
    return day - x.day;
}

public class Bill
{
private Money amount;
private Date dueDate;
private Date paidDate;
private String originator;

//paidDate set to null
public Bill (Money amount, Date dueDate, String originator) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.dueDate = dueDate;
    this.originator = originator;
    paidDate = null;
}

public Bill (Bill toCopy) {
    /*this.amount = toCopy.amount;
    this.dueDate = toCopy.dueDate;
    this.paidDate = toCopy.paidDate;
    this.originator = toCopy.originator;*/
}

public Money getAmount () {
    return amount;
}

public Date getDueDate () {
    return dueDate;
}

public String getOriginator () {
    return originator;
}

//returns true if bill is paid, else false
public boolean isPaid () {
    if (paidDate != null) { 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//if datePaid is after the dueDate, the call does not update anything and returns false.
//Else updates the paidDate and returns true
//If already paid, we will attempt to change the paid date.
public boolean setPaid (Date datePaid) {
    Date after = new Date(datePaid);
    if (after.isAfter(datePaid) == true) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        paidDate = datePaid;
        return true;
    }
}

//Resets the due date – If the bill is already paid, this call fails and returns false. 
//Else it resets the due date and returns true.
public boolean setDueDate (Date newDueDate) {
    if (isPaid() == false) {
        dueDate = newDueDate;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

//Change the amount owed.
//If already paid returns false and does not change the amount owed else changes 
//the amount and returns true.
public boolean setAmount (Money amount) {

}

public void setOriginator () {

}

//Build a string that reports the amount, when due, to whom, if paid, and if paid 
//the date paid
public String toString () {
    return "Amount: " + amount + " Due date: " + dueDate + " To: " + "originator" + " Paid?" + isPaid() + "Paid date: " + paidDate; 
}

//Equality is defined as each field having the same value.
public boolean equals (Object toCompare) {

}
```

}

Comment: Ummm... You implemented your own `Date` class? What `Date` objects are you using in `Bill`? Your own, or `java.util.Date`?

Comment: Yes, that was part of our assignment requirements. Not allowed to use java's Date class

Comment: Are you sure you're not pulling in `java.util.Date` in your `Bill` class?

Comment: Um...I don't think so...? I haven't imported it...

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in your method name. Your method is called (note the uppercase **F**):

```
public boolean isAFter (Date compareTo) {}
```

While you're calling it with (note the lowercase **f**):

```
if (after.isAfter(datePaid) == true) {}
```

On a side note, no idea why you're creating a new `Date` here:

```
Date after = new Date(datePaid);
```

The logic seems wrong, you're essentially just comparing the date to itself. Probably you want to compare to `dueDate`?